# Geometry nodes vector interpolation issue

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, mathematics, vector, interpolation

I'm trying to translate the vertices of one object in the direction of the nearest vertices of a second object. I know this can be achieved by blending the two vectors using a mixRGB node like this: [image]

[image]

My issue is that the possible positions are limited to the space between the two vectors. How would I do this so that I could translate past the limits in both directions? Sort of like the factor being any value, not just between zero and one.

I feel like this is simple vector math but I can't seem to articulate this problem into a relevant web search.

Comment: I'm not sure this what are you looking for? https://media.giphy.com/media/o29dx1IBSjXQjfVcED/giphy.gif

Comment: Feel free to transfer your tick... [@Chris 's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/255118/35559) is better for 3.1+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a very easy setup would be using this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To escape the limitation that RGB color-components can't have values outside 0-1, you can make your own 'Mix Vector' node-group, whose output is `Fac * B + (1-Fac) * A`:

[image]

... and then use it wherever you need an unclamped vector mix.

**Edit:** However! See [@Chris' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/255118/35559) for a simpler fix, since Blender 3.1's *Map Range* node can now accept Vector parameters.

Comment: i think you could simply use a map range vector node with clamp unchecked....

Comment: @Chris Quite right! I'm so used to chugging away with my little node group, I missed the 3.1 improvement in _Map Range_. :)

Comment: i am so proud that i could make it easier than the GREAT Robin Betts!!! :D

Comment: ok, i deleted it... ;)